# Command Handler never call using Masstransit

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I am writting microservices in .net core using Masstransit.
Here is my Startup.cs class where I registered Masstransit:

```
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<ConcertCommandHandler>();

            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var host = cfg.Host("localhost", "tickets", h => { h.Username("guest"); h.Password("guest"); });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "admin", e =>
                {
                    e.PrefetchCount = 16;

                    e.ConfigureConsumer<ConcertCommandHandler>(provider);

                    EndpointConvention.Map<TestCommand>(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/tickets/core"));
                });

                // or, configure the endpoints by convention
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
            }));
        });
```

I have simple controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Concert concert)
    {
        _concertRepository.CreateConcert(concert);
        _bus.Send(new ConcertCommand(concert.Id, concert.Name, concert.Place, concert.TicketAmount));
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

My command

```
    public ConcertCommand(int id, string name, string place, int ticketAmount)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Place = place;
        TicketAmount = ticketAmount;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public int TicketAmount { get; set; }
```

and my CommandHandler

```
public class ConcertCommandHandler : IConsumer<ConcertCommand>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ConcertCommand> context)
    {
         await context.Publish(new ConcertEvent(context.Message.Id, context.Message.Name, context.Message.Place, context.Message.TicketAmount));
    }
}
```

My ConcertCommandHandler never calls. I am new at Masstransit so can anybody help me?

How to configure my app? My idea is to my controller send command and that command publish message to RabbitMQ.

Comment: In Startup.cs class is EndpointConvention.Map<ConcertCommand> instead EndpointConvention.Map<TestCommand>. So can anybody help?

Comment: You need to start the bus

Comment: How to start and where?

Comment: You need to add the single line in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61906791/1882) linked.

Comment: I already have this:services.AddHostedService<BusService>(); and BusService is  public class BusService : IHostedService and still not working

Comment: Yeah, but what's the `BusService`?

Comment: BusService is class which inherit IHostedService and implemented Task StartAsync and Task StopAsync methods